# Activate JavaFX in already existing netbeans project

Tags: netbeans, javafx

I have an already existing netbeans project and i would like to have the possibility to add javaFX files from the netbeans menu. Is there any way to active JavaFx on an already existing project?

Answer (score 0):

Javafx is always available for any project even a swing application. For integration of the two see this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Comment: Yupp, i get everything with the fx gui to work, but what i would like to is actually the possibility of adding fx files from the netbeans menu new menu.

Comment: Oh you mean use the netbeans builder for javafx? No it is not. There might be a plugin but what you want is probably http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html also know as scene builder. There is the link to the archived versions. You should probably view tutorials on fxml and css if you want to use that.